# Multithreading with Word automation

Tags: .net, multithreading, ms-word, office-pia

I am working with MS Word 2007 in VB.NET using the PIAs.

Specifically I am doing some processing on multiple Word.Document objects in memory which are part of the same Word.Application object. Can I process each Word.Document in a separate thread or does Word automation require a single thread?

Thanks,

Jacob

Comment: The Office object is not single threaded. [Walkthrough: Multithreading with the BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx)

Comment: The walkthrough you linked to doesn't address office at all.

Also, you say that is isn't single threaded, but is it also thread safe?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `Interlocked Class` of [Multithreaded Programming with Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289496%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
lets you *you **safely** increment, decrement, exchange, and compare values from any thread*.
See also [Writing Code in Office Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608596.aspx) and [How to: Target Office Applications Through Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dww0e04a.aspx).

Comment: Down voted with no comment! Can anyone explain why this isn't a good idea?

Comment: Your answer does not respond to "Can I process each Word.Document in a separate thread or does Word automation require a single thread?"